# How to find $\int (x^2 dy + y dx)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

We had a question which goes like this:

> A particle is displaced from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ along $\rm y=x$. The force $F$ on the particle is $\rm ( x^2 \hat j + y \hat i)$. Find Work done during displacement.

What I did:

$$\rm W = \int F\cdot dx$$

$$\rm = \int ( y \hat i + x^2 \hat j)\cdot( dx \hat i + dy \hat j)$$

$$\rm = \int (y \ dx + x^2 \ dy)$$

The problem is that we can't integrate with respect to one variable keeping other as constant because both variables change.

What to do in this case? Also can we put $y = x$ since it was moved along this path? Also if we were not given this condition, how we find the integral then?

Comment: This is a line integral (Google it), you have to parametrize the path to get a parametrization $\gamma(t)$ and evaluate the integral of $F(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)$.

Comment: Just set $y=x$, as you suggested, and do the integrals from 0 to 1.

Comment: Parametrize the path $\gamma$. Here the parametrization $x(t)=t$, $y(t)=t$ with $t$ ranging over $[0,1]$ suggests itself.

Comment: A simple parametrization that works is $\gamma:[0,1]\to \Bbb R, t\mapsto(t,t)$ (here you use the fact that $y=x$ along the path.

Comment: What if we were not given $y = x$,  then how I would solve it?

Comment: You wouldn't unless the path was described in some manner. However, if the problem said "the line segment connecting $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, would you be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. As you mentioned in post and others mentioned in the comments, we can find the parameter $t$ which relates $y$ and $x$.

The particle was moved along $ x = y$, therefore this relation exists between all $ x$ and $\rm y$.

So we can replace $x$ with $y$ and vice versa, or replace both x and y with parameter $t$

$$ \therefore W = \int_{(0,0)}^{(1,1)}(x \ dx+y^2\ dy) = \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}\ \Big{|}^{(1,1)}_{(0,0)} = \frac{5}{6}$$

What if the particle wasn't moved along $ x= y$ ? How would we solve the integral:

$$ = \int (y \ dx + x^2 \ dy)$$

I think is the integral would have been *unsolvable*. The reason could be that the force $ F = (y \hat i + x^2 \hat j)$ is non conservative since $\nabla \times F \neq 0$. So work done would depend on curve along which particle was moved, and that path equation would need to be givenm